# How to view regular tribute of our faction to/from another one in Rome Total War?

Tags: rome-total-war

In the game, when making a diplomatic deal with the enemy, we have the option to offer/demand a regular tribute e.g. paying 100 denaris for 4 turns.

My question is after we offer/demand and get accepted, where would we see the history list of all regular tribute items?